# How do I get the output of a specific step in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this GitHub Actions workflow which runs tests, but now I am integrating slack notification in it. I want to get the output of the `Run tests` step and send it as a message in the slack step.

```
  - name: Run tests
    run: |
      mix compile --warnings-as-errors
      mix format --check-formatted
      mix ecto.create
      mix ecto.migrate
      mix test
    env:
      MIX_ENV: test
      PGHOST: localhost
      PGUSER: postgres

  - name: Slack Notification
    uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@master
    env:
      SLACK_MESSAGE: Run tests output
      SLACK_TITLE: CI Test Suite
      SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK }}
```

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You need to do 3 things:

1. Add an [`id`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsid) to the step you want the output from
2. Create the outputs using the [`GITHUB_OUTPUT`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) environment variable
3. [Use the id](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#steps-context) and the output name in another step to get the outputs and then [join](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#join) them into one message for slack

```yaml
- name: Run tests
  run: |
    echo "mix-compile--warnings-as-errors=$(mix compile --warnings-as-errors)\n" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    echo "mix-format--check-formatted=$(mix format --check-formatted)\n" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    echo "mix-ecto_create=$(mix ecto.create)\n" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    echo "mix-ecto_migrate=$(mix ecto.migrate)\n" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    echo "mix-test=$(mix test)\n" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  id: run_tests
  env:
    MIX_ENV: test
    PGHOST: localhost
    PGUSER: postgres

- name: Slack Notification
  uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2
  env:
    SLACK_MESSAGE: ${{join(steps.run_tests.outputs.*, '\n')}}
    SLACK_TITLE: CI Test Suite
    SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK }}
```

See [Metadata Syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputsoutput_id) for outputs name description

Comment: This worked for me, sorta. My output ends up with each line's leading whitespace truncated and each line is inexplicably surrounded by single-quotes. Is this happening for anyone else? This is very odd behavior and not well-documented. I'm doing the exact same thing; trying to capture output from a command and send it to Slack, though I'm using `pullreminders/slack-action`.

Comment: hmm, this caused the test step to register as success when it actually failed

Comment: Is it necessary to do anything special for whitespace in VALUE?

Comment: Please be aware that for Powershell, you should reference the environment variable "GITHUB_OUTPUT" like this `$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT`, otherwise the next step that evaluates the output variable will fail.

Comment: FWIW I find it more useful to include the key with the value via `toJSON(steps.run_tests.outputs)`

Answer (score 23):

The problem with the current [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59201610/1782) is that the result for the step will always be *success* since the test execution result is being masked by the `echo` command.

This modification to the last line should work in preserving the original exit status:

```
mix test 2>&1 | tee test.log
result_code=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
echo "::set-output name=mix-test::$(cat test.log)"
exit $result_code
```

Comment: Did you test this? The [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#exit-codes-and-error-action-preference) say that for `bash` and for the default shell on non-windows machines, the shell is run with `set -eo pipefail`. Doesn't the `-e` make a difference? I haven't tested, but I've also not seen a situation where using `-e` will allow the shell to continue executing the script when a command fails. I can test later to confirm

Comment: I have this running with no problems, yes

Comment: Be careful with this solution: if `test.log` contains multiple lines, the output `mix-test` will only receive *the first line of the file*. See: [Set-output Truncates Multiline Strings #26288](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26288)

Comment: [::set-output is deprecated](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/)

Answer (score 21):

I made an [action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/command-output) with the same interface as `run` that stores `stdout` and `stderr` in output variables to maybe simplify some cases like this:

```
- name: Run tests
  uses: mathiasvr/command-output@v1
  id: tests
  with:
    run: |
      mix compile --warnings-as-errors
      mix format --check-formatted
      mix ecto.create
      mix ecto.migrate
      mix test

- name: Slack Notification
  uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@master
  env:
    SLACK_MESSAGE: ${{ steps.tests.outputs.stdout }}         
    SLACK_TITLE: CI Test Suite
    SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK }}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add @smac89's solution was helpful but didn't quite work for me. I'm using a different Slack action (`pullreminders/slack-action`) to build more specific content. I found that I was getting single-quotes where each newline was, and my leading spaces on each line were also being truncated. After reading https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/403 and playing around, I found that in my case, I needed newlines to actually be escaped in the output (a literal `\n`), so I replaced `\n` characters with `\\n`. Then, I replaced regular space characters with a Unicode 'En Space' character.

Here's what worked:

Bash Run Step:

```
        Tools/get-changed-fields.sh src/objects origin/${{ env.DIFF_BRANCH }} > changed-fields.out
        output="$(cat changed-fields.out)"
        output="${output//$'\n'/\\n}"
        output="${output// / }"     # replace regular space with 'En Space'
        echo "::set-output name=changed-fields-output::$output"
```

Slack Notification Step:

````
    - name: Changed Fields Slack Notification
      if: ${{ success() && steps.summarize-changed-fields.outputs.changed-fields-output != '' && steps.changed-fields-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' }}
      env:
        SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN }}
      uses: pullreminders/slack-action@master
      with:
        args: '{\"channel\":\"${{ env.SUCCESS_SLACK_CHANNEL }}\",\"attachments\":[{\"color\":\"#36a64f\",\"title\":\"Changed Fields Report:\",\"author_name\":\"${{ github.workflow }} #${{ github.run_number }}: ${{ env.BRANCH }} -> ${{ env.TARGET_ORG }} (by: ${{ github.actor }})\",\"author_link\":\"${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.repository }}/runs/${{ github.run_id }}\",\"text\":\"```\n${{ steps.summarize-changed-fields.outputs.changed-fields-output }}\n```\"}]}'
````

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get multiple lines of output:

1. uses EOF as the delimiter [Doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings)
2. and sets the environment variable to the value of the command response (use 2>&1 convert stdout here)
3. receive environment variable in the next step

```
      - name: Unit Test
        id: unit_test
        run: |
          {
            echo 'test_output<<EOF'
            yarn test 2>&1
            echo EOF
          } >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```

```
      - name: Generate Unit Test Report
        if: success() || failure()
        id: unit_test_report
        run: |
          echo "$test_output"
          echo "Test_Suites=$(echo "$test_output" | grep 'Test Suites:')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "Test_Cases=$(echo "$test_output" | grep 'Tests:')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "Test_Time=$(echo "$test_output" | grep 'Time: ')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

```
      - name: Slack Notification
        if: success() || failure()
        uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2
        env:
          SLACK_CHANNEL: web-pr-notifications
          SLACK_COLOR: ${{ job.status }} # or a specific color like 'good' or '#ff00ff'
          SLACK_ICON: https://www.jenkins.io/images/logos/brno/brno.png?size=30
          SLACK_TITLE: 'CI Result :rocket:'
          SLACK_MESSAGE: ${{ toJson(steps.unit_test_report.outputs) }}
          SLACK_USERNAME: CI-Bot
          SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK }}
```