# Saving GITHUB_ENV Variable in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to save a variable name in one step, using [date](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html). But, in a later step, it seems to be undefined (or empty?). What am I missing here?

```
jobs:
  # Create release branch for the week
  branch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Format the date of next Tuesday
        id: tuesday
        run: echo "abbr=$(date -v+tuesday +'%y%m%d')" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Create a branch with next tuesday's date
        uses: peterjgrainger/action-create-branch@v2.0.1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          branch: release/${{ steps.tuesday.outputs.abbr }}
```

Error:

```
refs/heads/release/ is not a valid ref name.
```

Comment: If you want to output a value from a step, shouldn't it look more like e.g. https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/blob/ba4e452154f6569ee246fcda71a90220e6c83919/.github/workflows/push.yml#L46? That's what's shown in https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs and it works for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get output of a specific step in github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191913/get-output-of-a-specific-step-in-github-actions)

Answer (score 5):

I slightly changed your create branch step but your slo should work if you solve issue with date formatting.
[image]

I changed it and it works.

```yaml
jobs:
  # Create release branch for the week
  branch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Format the date of next Tuesday
        id: tuesday
        run: echo "abbr=$(date '+tuesday%y%m%d')" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Read exported variable
        run: |
          echo "$abbr"
          echo "${{ env.abbr }}"

      - name: Create a branch with next tuesday's date
        uses: peterjgrainger/action-create-branch@v2.0.1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          branch: release/${{ env.abbr }}
```

Here a logs from running this:

[image]

Comment: I don't see how the step is getting `abbr` seeing as you never created an environment variable called `abbr`. Also you are using the `env` context inside `run` which [doesn't](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#env-context) work

Comment: Are you sure what you are saying. I attached logs which proves different things than you are saying.

Comment: From what i recall `        run: echo "abbr=$(date '+tuesday%y%m%d')" >> $GITHUB_ENV` it created env variable.

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense now I wasn't aware of the [`GITHUB_ENV`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) variable

Comment: However, `echo "${{ env.abbr }}"` should not have worked, but you say it did which is weird...

Comment: Can you confirm one more time that this actually works. It seems to contradict the documentation

Comment: What can I say more than logs  both statements were printed, so it appears to be working

Comment: @smac89 did you get a chance to check it by yourself?