# How to access step output within github-script action

Tags: github-actions

I would like to use the output of a previous step in a `github-script` action. I tried:

```
    - name: Print step result
      uses: actions/github-script@v6
      with:
        script: |
          core.info(`Step result is: ${steps.captureStatus.outputs.response}`)
```

This gives me an error that `steps` is not defined.

The preceeding action is:

```
    - name: Capture status
      id: captureStatus
      uses: fjogeleit/http-request-action@v1
      with:
        method: GET
        url: "http://localhost:8091/iaf/api/server/health"
```

I read [Retrieve the output error from a github actions step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66358647/retrieve-the-output-error-from-a-github-actions-step), but from the answers on that question I could not find the answer of the present question.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use double curly brackets, so try

```
          core.info(`Step result is: ${{steps.captureStatus.outputs.response}}`)
```

instead of

```
          core.info(`Step result is: ${steps.captureStatus.outputs.response}`)
```

Comment: This works but is a security issue if the output is not fully in your control: the double-curly-expansion can lead to remote code execution. A safer choice is to map the output to a environment variable and use that variable instead