# GitHub Actions - Send output of debug msg from ansible playbook to Slack

Tags: ansible, github-actions

I want to send debug msg output from playbook to Slack and I am running this in GitHub actions.

GitHub Actions yml file (in .github dir)

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 2 * * *'

jobs:
  scheduled_test:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/base.yml
    with:
      ou_env: sandbox
      playbook: ping_hosts
    secrets:
      approle_id: ${{ secrets.APPROLE_ROLE_ID }}
      secret_id: ${{ secrets.APPROLE_SECRET_ID }}
      submodule_pat: ${{ secrets.SUBMODULE_PAT}}
      slack_webhook: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}
```

Slack step in ./.github/workflows/base.yml looks like.

```
      - name: Send slack notification
        uses: act10ns/slack@v1.6.0
        with: 
          webhook-url: ${{ secrets.slack_webhook }}
          status: ${{ job.status }}
          steps: ${{ toJson(steps) }}
        if: always()
```

Playbook looks like

```
- hosts: platform_linux:!skipped_group
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Ping Linux host
      ansible.builtin.ping:

    - name: Print percentage of Linux succeeded hosts
      debug:
        msg: "Success percentage for Linux is {{ 100 - ((ansible_play_hosts|length)/(ansible_play_hosts_all|length))*100 | round }}"

    - name: Print Linux hosts that failed
      debug:
        msg: "The Linux hosts that failed are {{ ansible_play_hosts_all | difference(ansible_play_hosts) }}"
```

I am able to send the fail or pass status on Slack, but I am not sure how to send the outputs from debug msg in playbook to Slack via Actions.

Comment: Does an approach with `id` like in [How do I get the output of a specific step in GitHub Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70405596/6771046) would work?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> *How to send the outputs from debug msg in playbook to Slack*

you could probably use the [`slack` module – Send Slack notifications](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/slack_module.html)

```yaml
- name: Send notification message via Slack
  community.general.slack:
    token: thetoken/generatedby/slack
    msg: 'Success percentage for Linux is {{ 100 - ((ansible_play_hosts|length)/(ansible_play_hosts_all|length))*100 | round }} and the Linux hosts that failed are {{ ansible_play_hosts_all | difference(ansible_play_hosts) }}'
  delegate_to: localhost
```

**Further Documentaion**

- [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/slack_module.html#examples)

Comment: Thank you @U880D. This is definitely doable, but I was hoping to send it all via GitHub Actions. And this way we don't have to store the token anywhere.

Comment: And also so that the overall status/steps/messages from Actions stay in the same slack message

Comment: So it seems that you like to [execute a given Ansible playbook on selected hosts](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/run-ansible-playbook), catch up the output and send that to Slack. Than, it has almost nothing to do with Ansible since it could be any program which becomes executed and producing output on `stdout`.