# How do I pass variable as argument to CLI parameter in YAML file?

Tags: bash, yaml, github-actions, cicd, detekt

I am trying to run `detekt` only on changed files in a pull request. The following doesn't work when I try to pass `CHANGED_FILES` as an argument to the `input` parameter for `detekt`.

```
# This workflow performs a static analysis of your Kotlin source code using
# Detekt.
#
# Scans are triggered:
# 1. On every push to the main branch
# 2. On every Pull Request targeting the main branch
name: detekt
## 2
on:
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for default and protected branches
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "detekt"
  detekt:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - name: "checkout"
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      # Determines changed files
      - name: "changed_files"
        run: |
          git fetch origin main:refs/remotes/origin/main
          export CHANGED_FILES=$(git --no-pager diff --name-only origin/main HEAD | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1 /')
          echo "Changed files: $CHANGED_FILES"
      - name: "detekt-all"
        uses: natiginfo/action-detekt-all@1.21.0
        env:
          CHANGED_FILES: ${{ CHANGED_FILES }}
        with:
          args: --fail-fast --config detekt-config.yml --plugins detekt/detekt-formatting-1.21.0.jar --input $CHANGED_FILES
```

I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Provided path '$CHANGED_FILES' does not exist!

I tried multiple other ways, but to no avail. I'm not familiar with YAML and I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax to do this, but I could not find any guidance about this specifically. How do we correctly pass it as an argument to a parameter instead of it being taken as the path itself? If I'm going about this the wrong way, then please let me know how to achieve this differently.

Comment: Each `run` represents a different shell. Exported env vars in one aren't available in the subsequent ones. See [Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) to fix that. Also, you cannot reference an env var directly in non-shell context i.e. `CHANGED_FILES: ${{ CHANGED_FILES }}` should be `CHANGED_FILES: ${{ env.CHANGED_FILES }}` after correctly setting it as the env var in the previous step.

Comment: @Azeem Thank you for the explanation and resource. I changed the env var accordingly, but the problem remains with the same error :(

Comment: Please edit your question and add an UPDATE section with the workflow that you tired.

Comment: See your updated workflow [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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).

Comment: Or, another alternative [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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).

Comment: BTW, there's this https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files/ action that you can use too to get the changed files and then process accordingly to pass on to `args`.

Comment: @Azeem The second option you provided regarding the variable worked! Thank you so much! And thanks for suggesting the changed-files action too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the output of a specific step in GitHub Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191913/how-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-specific-step-in-github-actions)